# Log Caller Class/Job Context When Spring Quartz Task Execute

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, scheduling, executorservice

I am writing a java/spring library to include in other projects that are using quartz.
I need it to log some information about the task/calling class everytime a job is executed.

For example, if a quartz job looks like this:

```
@Bean
public JobDetail jobADetail() {
    return JobBuilder.newJob(QuartzTaskA.class)
            .withIdentity("sampleJobA")
            .storeDurably().build();
}

@Bean
public Trigger jobATrigger(JobDetail jobADetail) {
    return TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
            .forJob(jobADetail)
            .withIdentity("sampleTriggerA")
            .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/10 * * ? * * *"))
            .build();
}

public class QuartzTaskA implements Job {
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) {
        log.info("QuartzA - the time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

I want it to log something like:

```
Job [QuartzTaskA] with details [sampleJobA] and trigger [sampleTriggerA] is starting
QuartzA - the time is now 12:07:39
```

I customize the SchedulerFactoryBean with a custom TaskExecutor that does a log before the task.run().
This works and I am able print the additional first line, but I can't figure out how to get the details/context to pass into the log.

```
@Configuration
public class SchedulerFactoryCustomizer implements SchedulerFactoryBeanCustomizer {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(SchedulerFactoryCustomizer.class);

    @Override
    public void customize(SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean) {
        Executor executor = SchedulerFactoryBean.getConfigTimeTaskExecutor();
        schedulerFactoryBean.setTaskExecutor(new CustomExecutor(executor);
    }

    private static class CustomExecutor implements Executor {
        final Executor executor;

        private CustomExecutor(Executor executor) {
            this.executor = executor;
        }

        @Override
        public void execute(Runnable task) {
            // This line here. How can I get the details/context to pass in?
            //log.info("Job {} with details {} and trigger {} is starting");
            task.run();
        }
    }
}
```

how can I get the details/context to pass into the log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a JobListener/TriggerListener

```
public class LoggingTriggerListener implements TriggerListener {

    @Override
    public String getName() {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void triggerFired(final Trigger trigger, final JobExecutionContext context) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean vetoJobExecution(final Trigger trigger, final JobExecutionContext context) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void triggerMisfired(final Trigger trigger) {

    }

    @Override
    public void triggerComplete(final Trigger trigger, final JobExecutionContext context, final Trigger.CompletedExecutionInstruction triggerInstructionCode) {

    }
}
```

It injects jobExecutionContext also.